# "Review this for me" questions

Tags: discussion

Sometimes we get questions that essentially amount to "review a product/project". Examples:

- [Google's ForPlay library, where does it fall down?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15776/googles-forplay-library-where-does-it-fall-down)
- [DarkGDK good or not?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15788/darkgdk-good-or-not)
- [What are the pro/cons of Unity3D as a choice to make games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8118/what-are-the-pro-cons-of-unity3d-as-a-choice-to-make-games)
- [Unreal engine 3 vs Id tech 3 vs Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15154/unreal-engine-3-vs-id-tech-3-vs-unity)

Are these good questions for the site? If so, under what conditions are they good questions?

There are two related categories of question I don't think should fall in this discussion:

- Questions asking for "the best" or "a good" library for some task, e.g. [Minimalistic JavaScript sprite manipulation libraries](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15795/minimalistic-javascript-sprite-manipulation-libraries), [What's the best Python 3D engine?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8290/whats-the-best-python-3d-engine), [Good GUI for OpenGL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/good-gui-for-opengl). I think it is difficult to make a decision about these a priori. If the task is not common there may only be one or two such libraries which are difficult to find. Even some very broad questions like the OpenGL one have turned out well as CW.
- Questions about best practices for some *task*, e.g. my own [Good 2D Platformer Physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/good-2d-platformer-physics) (which at the very least needs a better title), [To scene graph or not to scene graph](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15711/to-scene-graph-or-not-to-scene-graph), [Fixed time step vs Variable time step](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step). I think these are less emotional, less temporal, and answers borne out of experience are more valuable, than questions about specific products.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are good questions.  If someone has experience with the item in question, it is good for them to share their experience.

We're here to educate and facilitate learning and the exchange of information.  "RTFM" should only be a last resort.

-edit-
Another question that should NOT have been closed - this is very much answerable.

[How does one develop a first person shooter with a one man team?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15817/how-to-develop-a-first-person-shooter-with-a-one-man-team)

Comment: I'd originally closed that question because of flags, and because in the past similarly broad questions have been closed for the same reason.I asked about it in the chat, and Tetrad responded with his reasoning for not closing it, and I've re-opened it.

Comment: so long as they are truly game developer centric things, I can agree with this @noctrine -- we view gamedev as a more "holistic" site where all the skills and tools a game developer would reasonably use to build a *real* game are allowed.. of course we still have quality standards per the [faq] and [answer] and [ask]

Answer (score 3):

If one of these questions were posted on, for example Stack Overflow, if would probably be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com instead. Since no equivalent to "programmers" exists for gamedev I'd say that these are valid questions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is just the StackOverflow in me talking, but anytime I see "comparison" or "best", I think "way too subjective."

Even the comparison questions are subjective, because they assume that every point will be made and/or given proper weight. As I understand it, the point of an SE site is to be able to provide a single, definitive, *correct* answer, not a bunch of answers that you take as an aggregate. Comparisons seem like polling.

I'm not saying that they wouldn't produce useful posts. But SE is not a forum, and these kinds of questions seem more conducive to that kind of atmosphere.